# A notation question on how to properly denote a function that takes inputs only of a certain form.

Tags: notation, definition

Suppose I have a set $B = \{n^2 + n + 1 : n \in \mathbf{N}\}$ and I want to define a function $g: B \rightarrow \mathbf{N}$ that only accepts as it's arguments numbers of the form $n^2 + n + 1$ for $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and returns $n$. How would I say that in function notation when writing a proof? Would this be correct:

"Let $g: B \rightarrow \mathbf{N}$ be the function defined by $g(n^2 + n + 1) = n$."

That doesn't look right.

Comment: "Let $g\colon B\to\mathbb{N}$ be the map $g\colon n^2+n+1 \mapsto n$."

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Would I need to add after that, "for $n \in \mathbf{N}$", or would that be implied already?

Comment: It's implied by your definition of $B$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $g(m)= \frac{\sqrt{4m-3}-1}{2}$, if $m$ is always of the form $n^2+n+1$. This gives $g(m)=n$.

Comment: To see why, set $m=n^2+n+1$ and complete the square to get $m=\frac{(2n+1)^2+3}{4}$ and solve for $n$, noting that one root is always negative and so can be discarded.